# OpenCV How to Plot velocity vectors as arrows in using single static image

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am trying to plot velocity vectors like in matlab we use "quiver" function http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quiver.html

I need to port same methodology in C++ using OpenCV library.

I have heard There are a few optical flow methods, i.e. Lucas and Kanade (cvCalOpticalFlowLK) or Horn and Schunck (cvCalOpticalFlowHS) or Block Matching method (cvCalOpticalFlowBM)

but all of these functions take two images , while i need to use one image because i am working on fingerprints.

Kindly help me ...

[Edit]
Solution found

```
void cvQuiver(IplImage*Image,int x,int y,int u,int v,CvScalar Color,
                                            int Size,int Thickness){
cv::Point pt1,pt2;
double Theta;
double PI = 3.1416;

if(u==0)
    Theta=PI/2;
else
    Theta=atan2(double(v),(double)(u));

pt1.x=x;
pt1.y=y;

pt2.x=x+u;
pt2.y=y+v;

cv::line(Image,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line


Size=(int)(Size*0.707);


if(Theta==PI/2 && pt1.y > pt2.y)
    {
    pt1.x=(int)(Size*cos(Theta)-Size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(Size*sin(Theta)+Size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(Image,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line

    pt1.x=(int)(Size*cos(Theta)+Size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(Size*sin(Theta)-Size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(Image,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line
  }
else{
    pt1.x=(int)(-Size*cos(Theta)-Size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(-Size*sin(Theta)+Size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(Image,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line

    pt1.x=(int)(-Size*cos(Theta)+Size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(-Size*sin(Theta)-Size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(Image,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line
    }

}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am kind of completing the current answer here, which fails in giving the right size of each of the arrows' tip. MATLAB does it in a way that when an arrow is nearly a dot, it doesn't have any tip, while for long arrows it shows a big tip, as the following image shows.

[image]

To get this effect, we need to normalise the "tip size" of each of the arrow over the range of arrows' length. The following code does the trick

```
    double l_max = -10;

    for (int y = 0; y < img_sz.height; y+=10)                                                           // First iteration, to compute the maximum l (longest flow)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < img_sz.width; x+=10)
        {
            double dx = cvGetReal2D(velx, y, x);                                                        // Gets X component of the flow
            double dy = cvGetReal2D(vely, y, x);                                                        // Gets Y component of the flow

            CvPoint p = cvPoint(x, y);

            double l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);                                                             // This function sets a basic threshold for drawing on the image

            if(l>l_max) l_max = l;
        }
    }


    for (int y = 0; y < img_sz.height; y+=10)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img_sz.width; x+=10)
    {
        double dx = cvGetReal2D(velx, y, x);                                                        // Gets X component of the flow
        double dy = cvGetReal2D(vely, y, x);                                                        // Gets Y component of the flow

        CvPoint p = cvPoint(x, y);

        double l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);                                                             // This function sets a basic threshold for drawing on the image
        if (l > 0)
        {
            double spinSize = 5.0 * l/l_max;                                                        // Factor to normalise the size of the spin depeding on the length of the arrow

            CvPoint p2 = cvPoint(p.x + (int)(dx), p.y + (int)(dy));
            cvLine(resultDenseOpticalFlow, p, p2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA);

            double angle;                                                                           // Draws the spin of the arrow
            angle = atan2( (double) p.y - p2.y, (double) p.x - p2.x );

            p.x = (int) (p2.x + spinSize * cos(angle + 3.1416 / 4));
            p.y = (int) (p2.y + spinSize * sin(angle + 3.1416 / 4));
            cvLine( resultDenseOpticalFlow, p, p2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA, 0 );

            p.x = (int) (p2.x + spinSize * cos(angle - 3.1416 / 4));
            p.y = (int) (p2.y + spinSize * sin(angle - 3.1416 / 4));
            cvLine( resultDenseOpticalFlow, p, p2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA, 0 );

        }
   }
}
```

And this is an example of how this OpenCV code would look like

[image]

I hope this help other people Googling for the same issue.

Comment: @wolvorinePk I'm glad it helped somebody!

Comment: @Dan : May I suggest that you edit the code and have it in a function like "arrowedLine()". Which has a similar syntax to cv::line()?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the code from Dan and the suggestion of mkuse, here is a function with the same syntax as cv::line():

```
static void arrowedLine(InputOutputArray img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color,
int thickness=1, int line_type=8, int shift=0, double tipLength=0.1)
{
    const double tipSize = norm(pt1-pt2)*tipLength; // Factor to normalize the size of the tip depending on the length of the arrow
    line(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, line_type, shift);
    const double angle = atan2( (double) pt1.y - pt2.y, (double) pt1.x - pt2.x );
    Point p(cvRound(pt2.x + tipSize * cos(angle + CV_PI / 4)),
    cvRound(pt2.y + tipSize * sin(angle + CV_PI / 4)));
    line(img, p, pt2, color, thickness, line_type, shift);
    p.x = cvRound(pt2.x + tipSize * cos(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    p.y = cvRound(pt2.y + tipSize * sin(angle - CV_PI / 4));
    line(img, p, pt2, color, thickness, line_type, shift);
}
```

We will see if those maintaining the OpenCV repository will like it :-)

Comment: The next OpenCV version will have [cv::arrowedLine](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/a7006ac21c2e41b98be5d6635d75b3962000986b/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.rst#arrowedline) available

Answer (score 4):

The *cvCalOpticalFlowLK* does not plot velocity vectors, it **computes** these velocity vectors. If you do not have these vectors, you must call this function with two images. I guess you already have these vectors, and you just want to plot them.

In this case, you can use the [cv::line function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/drawing_functions.html#cv-line), for example:

```
cv::line(yourImage, cv::Point(baseX, baseY), cv::Point(endX, endY));
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks i tried the line with bunch of different ways to create an arrow using one single image,and now it is worked.

Comment: Plotting vectors without the sign (direction/arrow tip) is bad practise. I recommend the answer below.