# Plotting Velocity Vectors in a Binary Image Using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a binary (Black and White) image over which I want to plot velocity vectors of certain velocity. In MATLAB, we can use `quiver` to plot these vectors. I am looking for a solution to this problem in OpenCV using C++. I would be grateful if someone can share a solution to this. Although one of the solutions is provided in using the static image on SO ([OpenCV How to Plot velocity vectors as arrows in using single static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161351/opencv-how-to-plot-velocity-vectors-as-arrows-in-using-single-static-image)), its not clear of how to implement it on a binary image. I would be grateful if someone can guide me. 
Look forward to some suggestion towards implementation.

Comment: All you do is change the `color` parameter to a single grayscale value rather than an RGB triplet. Also note that the accepted answer uses the deprecated C-API call `cvLine` rather than the C++ `cv::line`.

Comment: @beaker I am more confused with the way the solution is being presented. I don't think they have shared the complete code. They have just put a part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to your problem: in this example I start with an rgb image coming from the webcam, then i convert it to grayscale and then to binary after applying a threshold.

The next step, when you have a binary image, is to convert it to RGB again (or BGR as the OpenCV convention) and draw whatever you want on it. The code for the arrow is a copypasta of what you have linked.

Hope it helps

```
cv::VideoCapture cam(n_source);
cam >> frame;

cv::Mat grey_image;
cv::Mat binary_image;  // Your binary image
cv::cvtColor(frame, grey_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::threshold(grey_image, binary_image, 100, 255, 0);

// Convert the binary to RGB
cv::Mat dst_rgb;
cv::cvtColor(binary_image, dst_rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR);

// Draw the arrow on the RGB image
int x = 200;
int y = 200;
int u = 100;
int v = 100;

cv::Point pt1,pt2;
double Theta;
double PI = 3.1416;

cv::Scalar Color(255,0,0);
int size = 5;
int Thickness = 5;

if(u==0)
    Theta=PI/2;
else
    Theta=atan2(double(v),(double)(u));

pt1.x=x;
pt1.y=y;

pt2.x=x+u;
pt2.y=y+v;

cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line


size=(int)(size*0.707);


if(Theta==PI/2 && pt1.y > pt2.y)
    {
    pt1.x=(int)(size*cos(Theta)-size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(size*sin(Theta)+size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line

    pt1.x=(int)(size*cos(Theta)+size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(size*sin(Theta)-size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line
  }
else{
    pt1.x=(int)(-size*cos(Theta)-size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(-size*sin(Theta)+size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line

    pt1.x=(int)(-size*cos(Theta)+size*sin(Theta)+pt2.x);
    pt1.y=(int)(-size*sin(Theta)-size*cos(Theta)+pt2.y);
    cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1,pt2,Color,Thickness,8);  //Draw Line
}

// Plot
cv::namedWindow("test rgb");
cv::imshow("test rgb", dst_rgb);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

An example: 
[image: blue line over binary image]

Comment: Sorry for responding late. I had fall ill so could not reply. Please let me know how to define velocity vector of certain magnitude in the figure.

Comment: In the code i wrote, the velocity vector (or a vector in general) is represented as a line between two points, `p1` and `p2` of type `cv::Point`. The magnitude of this vector is just the euclidean distance between `p1` and `p2`. 
`x` and `y` represent the starting point of the line and `u` and `v` are the x and y coordinates of `p2` relative to `p1`. In order tl modify the direction and magnitude of the vector you just need to rotate p2 and "stretch" it from p1. In other words just change the values of `size` and `Theta`

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. This code is just for one arrow but if we want to extend the arrows in a circular pattern with multiple arrows, can you suggest something towards this !!

Comment: In that case you just need to define a `std::vector<cv::Point> p1_vec` and `std::vector<cv::Point> p2_vec` where you store each `p1` and `p2` needed to draw a line. Now in a `for(int i=0; i<pt1_vec.size(); i++)` loop you just call `cv::line(dst_rgb,pt1_vec.at(i),pt2_vec.at(i),Color,Thickness,8);`
Remember that `cv::line` just modify the pixel values of dst_rgb as all the other drawing functions of opencv. What i mean is that there is no "object" or "memory locations" linked to the opencv line, so you can draw any line that you want without any increase in the memory usage

Comment: Accepted your answer. Many thanks for your answer. It did helped me a lot. Saved me a lot of time !!

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion I have come across cv::arrowedLine in OpenCV whose one of the usage is as follows:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

  using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
auto width = 320;
auto height = 320;
auto img = cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3); // create background image

auto center = cv::Point(width / 2, height / 2); // center point

int lineType = 8;
int thickness = 1;
double tipLength = 0.1;

img.setTo(255);                          // clear image - set to black (0) or white (255)

for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 15)
{
    auto angleRad = angle*CV_PI / 180.0;   // convert angle to radians

    auto length = 150;
    auto direction = cv::Point(length * cos(angleRad), length * sin(angleRad)); // calculate direction
    tipLength = .01 + 0.4 * (angle % 180) / 360;

    cv::arrowedLine(img, center + direction*0.5, center + direction, CV_RGB(255, angle, 0), thickness, lineType, 0, tipLength); // draw arrow!

    ++thickness;
    if (0 == angle % 45)
        thickness = 0;

    if (180 <= angle)
        lineType = CV_AA;
}
imshow("Arrowed Image", img);          // show image
waitKey();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```